# Call function directly after constructor "new"

Tags: javascript, internals

In many languages, to invoke some function directly on new instance I need to wrap it into braces:

```
 (new Date()).toString()
```

In JS `new Date().toString()` and `Date().toString()` give the same results as well.

Is it allowed to use function call immediately after instantiating new object in this way?

It looks like `new` keyword is optional sometimes. How is this interpreted by JS engine?

Comment: `new` is not "optional". It's required when you want the behavior it provides, and not when you don't.

Comment: you'd do well learning the nuances of the new keyword in js as well as understand the difference between the object oriented paradigm vs the prototypical paradigm.

Comment: Please note carefully that `new Date().toString()` and `Date().toString()` do give the same result. However, `new Date()` is a date object while `Date()` is a string. It is "coincidental" that toString() gives the same result for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In many languages, to invoke some function directly on new instance I need to wrap it into braces
>   Is it allowed to use function call immediately after instantiating new object in this way?

I think the problem here is potential ambiguity. While `(new Date()).toString()` is clear, `new Date().toString()` could *(theoretically)* mean either `(new Date()).toString()` or `new (Date().toString)()`.

But here comes [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to the rescue.

the `new (with argument list)` operator has a higher precedence than a function call. Therefore the order of execution in `new Date().toString()` is as clear *(at least to the engine)* as the order in wich these math operations have to be executed `2 + 3 * 4`

But beware, in JS you can also write `new Date;` without the brackets, and this operator `new (without argument list)` has a lower precedence than a function call. So `new Date.toString()` is interpreted as `new (Date.toString)()` and you get an Error that `toString()` is no constructor.

> It looks like new keyword is optional sometimes. How is this interpreted by JS engine?

Not at all. This ain't a JS feature this is a quirk in the implementation of these functions/classes/constructors

A bit like these implementations:

```
function Foo(){
    if(!(this instanceof Foo)) 
        return new Foo();

    this.foo = 42;
}

//or something like
function Bar(){
    return Object.create(Bar.prototype, {
        bar: { value: 42 }
    });
}

console.log(new Foo(), Foo());
console.log(new Bar(), Bar());
```

And again beware. Due to added security/failsafety you can't implement something like that with the new `class` keyword. It adds *(hidden)* code to ensure that these constructors are always called with the `new` keyword, otherwise the constructor throws an error.

**Edit:**
For example the Array constructor works like described above, but as it seems (as pointed out in [Freeman Lambdas answer](/a/43712206/6567275)) the Date constructor has *(defined by the spec)* two different return values, depending on wether you call it as a function or as a constructor.

Comment: So eventually the rules are `new Date().toString()`=`(new Date()).toString()`  and `new Date.toString()`=`new (Date.toString)()`

Comment: @ANTARA yes, that's the order in wich it is interpreted/resolved; like `2+3*4` is interpreted as `2+(3*4)` and NOT as `(2+3)*4`. That is called operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

[EMCAScript spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-constructor)

> The Date constructor is the %Date% intrinsic object and the initial
>   value of the Date property of the global object. When called as a
>   constructor it creates and initializes a new Date object. When Date is
>   called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String
>   representing the current time (UTC).

```js
// with new
const a = new Date();
console.log(typeof a); // object
console.log(a instanceof Date); // true
console.log(a.toString()); // date formatted string

// without new
const b = Date();
console.log(typeof b); // string
console.log(b instanceof Date); // false
console.log(b.toString()); // date formatted string
```

As you can see this behavior of Date is explicitly described in the language spec, it has nothing to do with *new* being optional. 
You can discover a lot about *new* just by reading through these popular questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+new+keyword

Finally, you can use a newly created object immediately. There is no need to wrap it in parenthesis.